# Enter credit card details on the PayPal site (rather than my own hosted site)

Tags: security, paypal, credit-card, recurring-billing, pci-compliance

Can I get users to enter credit card details on the **PayPal** site, rather than my own when setting up a recurring payments profile for direct credit card payments?

When setting up a recurring payments profile for a user who wishes to subscribe to my service, I currently follow the standard recurring payment flow (as shown in the PayPal API examples):

1. Use the REST API to create a billing plan and agreement.
2. Redirect the user to the PayPal site.
3. User logs in/registers on PayPal site and confirms their acceptance there.
4. PayPal redirects them back to my site for final confirmation of the billing agreement.
5. Once they have confirmed on my site, billing commences and we start listening for IPN's.

However, it seems that if you want to use **direct** credit card payments (i.e. the customer does not have/want a PayPal profile), you have to capture the credit card details on your **own** site and pass them through to PayPal on the API call. Is there a way to move the credit card detail capturing to the PayPal site itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PayPal supports this arrangement; they call it hosted pro or hosted sole solution. However, it's classic, not the new REST.

PayPal's newer direct credit card APIs use vaulting, but I don't believe they come with a fully PayPal-hosted page that would avoid all PCI complications for you.

You might also want to look at Braintree's solution, which integrates into your page but handles encrypting & tokenizing the card details so you don't have to worry about PCI.

Comment: Thanks for all the info! Sadly the features we need aren't supported in our country, so we decided to go with FastSpring owing to their customer support and the fact that they actually support everything we need out the box!